# Can one return to the UK following international travel whilst on immigration bail?

Tags: visas, uk, customs-and-immigration, overstaying

My visa to the UK was expired, and I got arrested due to a misunderstanding and false suspicion of criminal activity. The criminal allegation was quickly dropped, but upon being booked into jail, they found that my visa was expired and informed me that I would likely be removed the next day. Instead I was released on granted immigration bail for three months. During those three months, what is my status in the UK? I am meant to report to a particular address on my bail conclusion date, but in the meantime until that date, could I travel to other countries, and then smoothly return to the UK before my bail date to report to the home office as instructed?

Cheers

Comment: Your visa has expired. That makes you an overstayer. If you leave, what makes you think you'll be allowed to return? You'll also find it difficult to get another visa.

Comment: Because I have a bail date scheduled for me to attend!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

No, you will have left the UK and not be eligible to return (as you have no lawful status allowing you to return.)

Regarding your current status, it ends if you leave the UK - the UK wont pursue any criminal action as their goal is for you to leave the country, which you would have done.

> A grant of immigration bail ends when the person to whom it is granted is:

> - No longer liable to be detained and the Secretary of State is not considering whether to make a deportation order against the person;
> - Granted leave to enter or remain in the UK;
> - Detained under one of the provisions mentioned in Eligibility for Immigration Bail; or
> - Removed from, or ***otherwise leaves, the UK.***

https://www.gherson.com/blog/overview-immigration-bail-and-detention

Answer (score 4):

The immigration bail means: You have no right to be in the UK. But instead of removing you instantly, we are nice and give you time to put things in order, quit your job, cancel your rental agreement, hire a removal company to take your stuff to a place in the eu that you start renting.

Once you leave you have no right to return.