# On immigration bail in England, could I fly to Scotland until my bail date? Northern Ireland?

Tags: uk, customs-and-immigration, covid-19, removal, deportation

The question is in the title, but I'm wondering what possible consequences it could have...

Thanks

Comment: Related? https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/159153/can-one-return-to-the-uk-following-international-travel-whilst-on-immigration-ba

Comment: @BernhardDöbler it's not a dupe though, since the OP is not looking to leave the UK. It's similar to asking if someone with deferred action in the USA can fly from New York to Hawaii.

Comment: The UK government website says that you can have a range of additional conditions imposed on your bail, so while it may be true in many cases that you can travel within the UK (which would include Scotland and NI), you would have to check the specific conditions of your bail to answer for certain, and post the full conditions of your bail before anyone can answer for you. https://www.gov.uk/bail-immigration-detainees/conditions-of-your-bail

Comment: How is this considered on topic? Since immigration bail is involved it becomes completely a legal question, and one in which no SE can answer. Why on Earth would the OP be asking Random Internet Strangers of unknown competence or ability to voice an opinion on something that can have drastic and long-lasting affect on their future. OP: talk to your lawyer, and if you don't have one, get one.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because its not about travel but about the limitations imposed by immigration bail, which might be specific to the OP

Answer (score 1):

Yes, assuming you have appropriate ID as determined by the airline (such as UK driving licence), there is no restriction on internal travel. If you are required to attend a reporting centre, obviously you should make sure your travel doesn't conflict with that (allowing for the possibility of flight cancellation).

Comment: What about to Jersey or Guernsey, and what about with one's non-UK, non-European passport?

Comment: Would the Home office not receive API for such flights?

Comment: Jersey and Guernsey are not in the UK. I think you would be ill advised to leave the UK while on immigration bail (not least because you'd likely forfeit any appeal against your removal). I don't know if the Home Office receive API for internal flights, but it hardly matters, because there's no general restriction on domestic travel for those on immigration bail.

Comment: Right. But Guernsey and Jersey would both be external travel then, in that sense?

Comment: @JosephP People who are on immigration bail are in the middle of proceedings brought by the UK government to deport them from the UK. If an immigration bailee goes to Guernsey or Jersey, _that person has left the UK_. That person will not be permitted to re-enter the UK.

Comment: @JosephP. those questions are not part of the OP's... if you have your own (different) question, please ask it, not in comments starting a discussion.